# find first consecutive values groups by ids

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe where I want to group first consecutive for each id

```
id   value 
a1   1
a1   3
a1   4
a2   1
a2   2 
a2   3
a2   5
a2   8
a2   9
```

I want an out put where it identifies "first" consecutive group for each id , I have tried difference measures but only in vain as it returns id values which are consecutive after a break.

I want an output of this kind

```
id  value
a1  1
a2  1
a2  2
a2  3
```

would appreciate suggestions

Comment: Can you explain `a2  2,
a2  3` in output?

Comment: basically for id a2 the values 1,2,3 are first consecutive values for that id . and values 8,9 are another group that are sequential  for the same id . I was looking for the first consecutive values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is create consecutive groups by compare difference for not equal `q` with cumulative sum and then for first groups test first values by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) or [`GroupBy.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html):

```
s = df['value'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
df1 = df[s.groupby(df['id']).transform('first').eq(s)]
#alternative
#df1 = df[s.groupby(df['id']).transform('min').eq(s)]
print (df1)
   id  value
0  a1      1
3  a2      1
4  a2      2
5  a2      3
```